# Finding points on a surface which contain tangent planes parallel to the axis-planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f(x,y,z) = \frac{3}{2-x} + \frac{1}{y-z}$ and let $S$ be the surface given by the equation $ f(x,y,z) = 1 $

Are there any points on $S$ where the tangent plane to $S$ is parallel to the $xy$, $xz$ or $yz$–planes? If such points exist find them. If no such points exist, explain why.

In order to locate these parallel tangent planes I figured I have to see what $x,y,z$ values exist such that the gradient vector of $S$ is a scalar multiple of the gradient vector of each plane.

So beginning with the $xy$-plane.

The gradient vector of $S$ is $ (\frac{3}{(2-x)^2}, \frac{-1}{(y-z)^2}, \frac{1}{(y-z)^2}) $

The gradient vector of the $xy$-plane is $ (0,0,1) $

Hence, we solve for values of $x,y,z$ where

$(\frac{3}{(2-x)^2}, \frac{-1}{(y-z)^2}, \frac{1}{(y-z)^2}) = \lambda (0,0,1) = (0,0,\lambda)$

$\iff x = 2, y = z, (y-z)^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda}$

Is this approach correct. It seems to me there are infinitely many points satisfying the above conditions.

If I am right, do I simply perform the same operations on the other planes?

If I am wrong, could someone explain to me where I'm going wrong. I am much more interested in understanding why something is done, rather than just being given the answer.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You were fine till your conclusion about x = 0 and  y = z. Re-think those.

Comment: I meant $x = 2$ (edited). Does it not exist since $\frac{c}{0}$ is undefined?

Comment: Yes, you cannot have 3/0 = 0 so x = 2 cannot be correct. What about any other x?

Comment: It seems to me no x's satisfy this condition. And the same goes for y's and z's. Does that mean no tangent exists for the xy-plane? I think we can say the same about the other two planes too?

Comment: Yes, that looks good.